# Alternative of MULTICOL tag in HTML or HTML5

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I want to display my records like Multiocol tag holds.  tag may be no longer to use as only netscape supports.

Is there any alternative tag to support same like Operation [here](http://www.the-pope.com/dirmen5.html) is an example

Comment: You can use css3 to get the same effect. Here is an example:
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}

Comment: There is not enough info in this question to figure out what you actually want. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

```
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I already look that option also. I wanted to be like MULTICOL tag with selectable option.

Comment: selectable option what is the exact requirement any particular column you need to select via css or what?

Comment: is this what you want..check the sample https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 to achieve the results like this:

```
div{
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    column-count: 6;
}
```

Or 2d-transforms like [Multi-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547795/list-divide-into-multiple-columns)

And here is one with [selectable option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213160/select-multiple-html-with-columns-possible)